# print each node of data in a csv on the next line?

Tags: python, csv

I have been trying print all the columns of a .csv file that has four columns, no header into on column. Basically having python write a new line for every column.

Here is my code so far, I thought the split(',') function would split each node at the delimiter and write the next data point on the next line. I was wrong...
    import os
    import csv

```
os.chdir('/users/brettzajac/Documents/CSV_Parser')

try:
    data = open('file.csv', 'r', encoding = 'utf-8')
    for each_line in data:
        try:
            row = each_line.split(',', -1)
            print(row)
        except:
            pass
    data.close()
except:
    print('The file is missing!')
```

here is a sample of the data i have.

```
.22 MAG,SIMMONS - .22 MAG RIFLESCOPE,SIMMONS,Magnification,3-9X32
.22 MAG,SIMMONS - .22 MAG RIFLESCOPE,SIMMONS,Magnification,4X32
.22 MAG,SIMMONS - .22 MAG RIFLESCOPE,SIMMONS,Finish,MATTE
.22 MAG,SIMMONS - .22 MAG RIFLESCOPE,SIMMONS,Finish,SILVER
```

my results are:

```
[.22 MAG,SIMMONS - .22 MAG RIFLESCOPE,SIMMONS,Magnification,3-9X32]
[.22 MAG,SIMMONS - .22 MAG RIFLESCOPE,SIMMONS,Magnification,4X32]
[.22 MAG,SIMMONS - .22 MAG RIFLESCOPE,SIMMONS,Finish,MATTE]
[.22 MAG,SIMMONS - .22 MAG RIFLESCOPE,SIMMONS,Finish,SILVER]
```

any way i am stumped maybe i just don't know what to search for on google/stackOverFlow so if i duplicated some one else's question i apologize. thanks for any help or points in the right direction.

Regards,
Zajac

Comment: You say: "I thought the split(',') function would split each node at the delimiter and write the next data point on the next line."  Did you consider looking at [the documentation for `split`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) to see what it *actually* does?

Comment: I don't believe this code prints the data you've shown.

Comment: I recommend using http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html instead

Comment: I'll will read the documentation, and i am sorry if i have offended you BrenBarn. wRAR it does print the data shown. piokuc thank you for the link i have been search the internet all weekend trying to figure this out. I appreciate your patience as i am fairly new at this whole programing thing and when i get stuck or cannot find or am not sure what to look for i ask. Again my apologies for asking such an obviously dumb question.

Comment: If you want to treat a CSV file, you must read the doc on the subject, and learn about it by reading questions-answers of stackoverflow.com on the subject. There is a search feature.

Comment: I hadnt understood your question. Read too rapidly. - In fact , write ``'\n'.join(each_line.split(','))`` and you obtain what you want. I don't see the meaning of -1 in the split() function. - Or do ``each_line.replace(',','\n')`` and print that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of

```
print(row)
```

Try

```
for cell in row:
    print cell
```

Comment: thank you georgerw use the    for cell in row: print(cell) works like a charm. I really appreciate your help I plan on perfecting my research methods and bookmarking the python documentation. Thank you again for not chewing me out for asking a dumb question and pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

`split` just returns a list, it is not related to printing, to newlines, whatever. If you want to print a list with each element on a new line you need to it manually, for example with a `for` loop.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import csv

with open('file.csv', 'rb', encoding = 'utf-8') as f:
    r = csv.reader(f)
    li = list(r)

fields = '...'.join( '{:.<%ds}' % max(map(len,cat))
                     for cat in zip(*li) )

print 'fields :\n%r\n\n' % fields


print '\n'.join(fields.format(*el) for el in li)
```

Comment: thank you again eyquem I will try this as well as work on my searching skills and doc reading as not to ask silly questions anymore.

Comment: You must be not so timorous. We don't do reproaches to you, just some "shaking". There are no silly questions, everybody has the right to do mistakes. But there are some inappropriate manners to program. If you don't read the doc, it's not so good. An you can do essays: for ex. define ``li = [12, 'gh','ki']`` and do ``print li`` you'll see that the elements of list ``li`` aren't printed each on its own line. And print ``each_line.split(',')``, you'll see it's a list. Then , guess if it will be printed on several lines...